# Issue with UIView subclass transparency

Tags: ios, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to draw a subclass of UIView over top of an GLKView. The subclass works as a "health" indicator for the game, and transparency is required, outside of the drawn area.

[image]

I have tried using

```
 self.opaque = NO;
[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

which have no effect, as well as pre-filling the view with a clear colour:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(ctx, rect);
```

which also has no effect.
Simply setting the alpha with

```
self.alpha = 0.0
```

also has no effect.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: The subclass is placed in interface builder, if it matters.